# xCode behaves Strangely when initializing array

Tags: nsmutablearray, xcode5

i dont know what is wrong with code below

```
        #import "ViewController.h"

        @interface ViewController ()
        {
            NSMutableArray * buttons;
            NSMutableArray * centers;

            int counter;
            int index;
        }
        @end


        @implementation ViewController

        -(void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            buttons = [NSMutableArray new];
            centers = [NSMutableArray new];//error here expected identifier or '('
        }
//other methods
    @end
```

i am getting two arrays, xcode works normally for buttons but it gives error for centers when creating. What may be the problem?

note: i tried deleting derived data.

Comment: Have you tried deleting that entire line (and maybe the line before and after). Especially when copying and pasting code you might insert invisible characters which may lead to those errors.

Comment: i tried but nothing changed

Comment: it is so strange now. i changed the name of array "centers" to "buttons2" and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know this isn't the question you asked, but I would like to suggest an alternative to instantiating variables in viewDidLoad.  It's something called "lazy instantiation", and it looks like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)buttons
{
     if (!_buttons) _buttons = [NSMutableArray new];
     return _buttons;
}
```

When you need to reset the array, just set it to nil.  It won't reallocate the memory until you call it again.

P.S.  Whatever you do, don't call self.buttons within that method, or you will create an infinite loop.